# Do foreign debts require special treatment in a bankruptcy petition?

Tags: united-states, bankruptcy

I have foreign debts, and I'm aware that while they cannot be discharged in the USA where I am filing, they still need to be declared.

My question is simply if they should be included with the domestic debts on the various schedules, without drawing special attention to them, or if they need to be isolated or declared in some other way?

For a simple question I have had a lot of trouble trying to find an answer to this.